# Confused with defer wg.Done and channel

Tags: go

I encounter a problem about using defer wg.Done and channel.

If I coded like below, there is no problem.

```
for i := 0; i < ntasks; i++ {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func(args DoTaskArgs) {
        // defer wg.Done()
        for {
            worker := <-registerChan
            ok := call(worker, "Worker.DoTask", &args, nil)
            if ok {
                wg.Done()
                // go func() {
                registerChan <- worker
                // }()
                break
            }
        }
    }(DoTaskArgs{jobName, mapFiles[i], phase, i, n_other})
}
wg.Wait()
```

But if I use `defer wg.Done()`, the code would be stucked, unless wrap the `registerChan <- worker` with `go func`.

```
for i := 0; i < ntasks; i++ {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func(args DoTaskArgs) {
        defer wg.Done()
        for {
            worker := <-registerChan
            ok := call(worker, "Worker.DoTask", &args, nil)
            if ok {
                // go func() {
                registerChan <- worker
                // }()
                break
            }
        }
    }(DoTaskArgs{jobName, mapFiles[i], phase, i, n_other})
}
wg.Wait()
```

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first off, your channel use is confused and will block. In the goroutine it reads from the channel. But nothing wrote into it.

I don't think your problem has anything to do with defer.

Comment: thx. But i am stil confused with why after adding `go func` it would be ok.

Comment: @glc-seven Because a go function is executed asynchronously. It doesn't wait for the channel write to complete. In fact if no one is listening to the channel the goroutines would just stack up more and more until the program crashes.